# Script for run script on vbs

Tags: scheduled-task, vbscript

Hello everybody I have a script on vbscript

```
Dim WSHShell, WinDir, Value, wshProcEnv, fso, Spath

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim objFSO, objFileCopy
Dim strFilePath, strDestination

Const OverwriteExisting = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set windir = objFSO.getspecialfolder(0)
objFSO.CopyFile "\dv.rt.ru\SYSVOL\DV.RT.RU\scripts\shutdown.vbs", windir&"\", OverwriteExisting

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\" _
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
JobID = "1"

Set colScheduledJobs = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob")
For Each objJob in colScheduledJobs
objJob.Delete
Next

Set objNewJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")
errJobCreate = objNewJob.Create _
(windir & "\shutdown.vbs", "**093000.000000+660", _
True, 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16 OR 32 OR 64, ,True, JobId)
```

How make that shutdown.vbs not run once at 9:30 but run for 9:30 to 12:00

Comment: user31568: Your last question (an exact copy/paste of this one) got closed as "not a real question" meaning we couldn't tell exactly what you where looking for. You might want to edit in some more detail about what you are trying to do, what you have already tried, and what errors you are seeing.

Comment: Crossposted: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854968/script-for-run-script) and [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/142355/script-for-run-script-on-vbs).

Comment: Since the user has no interest in following up on his question (even though an answer was proposed), can we close this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a `Create` for each time that you want to schedule the task.

```
errJobCreate = objNewJob.Create _
(windir & "\shutdown.vbs", "********093000.000000+660", _
True, 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16 OR 32 OR 64, ,True, JobId)
errJobCreate = objNewJob.Create _
(windir & "\shutdown.vbs", "********093500.000000+660", _
True, 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16 OR 32 OR 64, ,True, JobId)
errJobCreate = objNewJob.Create _
(windir & "\shutdown.vbs", "********094000.000000+660", _
True, 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16 OR 32 OR 64, ,True, JobId)
.
.
.
```

Or set the time in a variable and increment it and do the `Create` in a loop.